# numeric text box and date picker not working in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a dynamic table. When I adding row numeric text box and date picker working fine. But when I edit this row after saving numeric text box and date picker not working though when I check the row using firebug the numeric and date text box contains the same class as before.

Here is my code

Table Html

```
<tr class="entryForm1">
    <td style="padding: 7px 20px;"><input type="text" /></td>
    <td style="padding: 7px 20px;"><input type="text" class="numericTextbox" /></td>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option>Development</option>
            <option>Hr</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 7px 20px;"><input type="text" class="datepicker" /></td>
    <td style="padding: 7px 20px;">  <img src="~/images/icons/save.png" class='btnSave' alt="Edit" style="border-width: 0px;" />
        <img src="~/images/icons/delete.png" alt="Delete" style="border-width: 0px;" class='btnDelete' /></td>
</tr>
```

The Save method on js file

```
function Save() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");

    var tdTAge = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdDesignation = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");

    var tdDate = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
    var tdIcon = par.children("td:nth-child(5)");
    tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());

    tdTAge.html(tdTAge.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdDesignation.html(tdDesignation.children("select").val());

    tdDate.html(tdDate.children("input[type=text]").val());


    tdIcon.html("<img src='../../images/icons/update.png' class='btnEdit'/><img src='../../images/icons/delete.png' class='btnDelete'/>");

    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
}
```

And the edit method which creates the problem

```
function Edit() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdAge = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdDesignation = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdDate = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
    var tdIcon = par.children("td:nth-child(5)");
    tdName.html("<input type='text' value='" + tdName.html() + "'/>");
    tdAge.html("<input type='text' id='txtAge' class='numericTextbox'  value='" + tdAge.html() + "'/>");
    tdDesignation.html("<select>" +
            "<option>Development</option>" +
            "<option>H</option>" +
            "</select>");

    tdDate.html("<input type='text' class='datepicker hasDatepicker' value='" + tdDate.html() + "'/>");

    tdIcon.html("<img src='../images/icons/save.png' class='btnSave'/>");

    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
}
```

And when I adding a new row

```
function Add() {

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    var newRow = $('#tblCadastro tbody>tr:first').clone(true);


    $('input', newRow).val('').
            filter('.hasDatepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
    $('#tblCadastro tbody').append(newRow);
    newRow.appendTo('#tblCadastro tbody').show('slow');
    $('input', newRow).val('').
            filter('.hasDatepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').attr('id', '').datepicker();

    $('select', newRow).filter('.dropDown').attr('id', 'o1');
    $('div', newRow).filter('.chzn-container').attr('id', 'o1');

    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
}
```

Advance thanks.

Comment: please use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: try to change class selector to this $(document).find("yourClass")...etc

Comment: From where you are getting     'this' in save and edit functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue using

```
$("#tblCadastro").on("keypress", "#txtAge", function (evt) {


    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
      && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
});
```